# For archival purposes, does this SE have a mechanism for highlighting a question may be outdated?

Tags: discussion

While reviewing a question regarding Magic the Gathering, I came to the realization that my downloaded copy of the Comprehensive rules was outdated. In one of the recent updates, they inserted "701.6 Create."

Aside from the date stamp, are there other mechanisms to queue to readers that the answers may be slightly out of date?

Related: for those with answers on Magic the Gathering, or others that are interested in the archival strength of the SE, the rules changes may cause need for answer edits.

Comment: It is actually possible for an answer to be out of date when it is posted if the author has outdated information which makes it harder to determine what is outdated and what isn't

Answer (score 4):

There is no system for marking posts as "potentially out of date".

Clearly, that sort of thing would be hard to automate; in principle, every answer is potentially out of date.

If it was possible to manually mark a question or answer as out of date, it would always be better to comment or edit with the necessary correction.

In addition, as diego points out, there is a bounty reason

> **Current answers are outdated:** The current answer(s) are out-of-date and require revision given recent changes

So if you find a question with significantly out-of-date answers, you can post a bounty to encourage people to update the answers.

Comment: I understand the complication in automating such a thing, largely since there isn't integration between SE and Wizards. Mostly, I just balked at the "ask a question" button, while wanting to recommend people check their answers. Planning on how I'll cycle through mine. It is regrettable answers aren't associated with a tag, like "mtg-rules" for easy  searching.

Comment: Probably at least 90% of the answers on questions with the tag [magic-the-gathering] are rules answers.

Comment: It also might be useful to point out that one of the bounty reasons is "**Current answers are outdated**:The current answer(s) are out-of-date and require revision given recent changes." So if you find an answer that is out of date you can create a bounty to have someone else come and update it if you don't want to.